# Fail sbt build when there are incompatible evictions

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to make my build fail when there are some incompatible libraries detected. I came up with something like this:

```
test := Def.sequential(
  Def.task {
    if (evicted.value.reportedEvictions.nonEmpty) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("There are some incompatible classpath evictions warnings. You can suppress them with dependencyOverrides setting.")
    } 
  },
  test in Test
).value
```

so I redefine test to fail, but its looks a bit over-engineered. IS there a simpler solution? Preferably without creating custom task.

Comment: Which version of sbt?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using sbt 1.x, so I think the right way to do this is:

```
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("This is the tasks that checks that everything is ok before you start your tests")

myTask := ???

(test in Test) := (test in Test).dependsOn(myTask).value
```